# Cómo poner un valor verdadero o falso el usuario en un boolean

Tags: java, poo, validación, booleano

Hola chicos estoy haciendo un pequeño programa en java en donde el usuario se encuentra asegurado o no
para lo cual usuario debes teclear la palabra "si" o "no" en caso que si debe aparecer el mensaje que este asegurado , en caso que no debe aparecer no dispone de seguro solo que al ejecutar el programa todo me sale en false, a continuación adjunto el código de mi programa.

```
public class Principal
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    boolean seguro;
    String valor="";
    seguro=Boolean.parseBoolean(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Cuenta con seguro?"+valor));
    if(valor.compareToIgnoreCase("si")==0&&seguro){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n Es un trabajador asegurado");
      seguro=false;
    }
    else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n Lo sentimos no cuenta con seguro"); // pendiente
     seguro=true;
    } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error de lógica en tu código. Deberías recuperar en `valor` lo que el usuario haya escrito y luego entonces hacer la comparación, el problema es que `valor` no tiene el dato que escribió el usuario al momento de comparar.

Podrías resolverlo así:

```
public class Principal
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Recuperamos lo que se haya escrito
        String valor=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Cuenta con seguro?");
        //Usar equalsIgnoreCase sería mejor, pues devuelve un booleano
        boolean seguro = valor.equalsIgnoreCase("si");
        //Para simplificar, podemos evitar el if, usando un ternario
        String msg = (seguro) ? "\n Es un trabajador asegurado" : "\n Lo sentimos no cuenta con seguro";
        /*
            Se mostrará uno de los dos mensajes según lo que haya ocurrido
            y seguro valdrá true o false según el caso 
            por si quieres usarlo de algún modo
        */
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msg);
    }
}
```

Si el valor de `seguro` no interesa para un uso posterior, puedes todavía simplificar el código de este modo:

```
public class Principal
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String valor=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Cuenta con seguro?");
        String msg = (valor.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) ? "\n Es un trabajador asegurado" : "\n Lo sentimos no cuenta con seguro";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo  ya lo voy a probar ahi te aviso si me funciono

Comment: si me funciono me parece interesante el uso del operador ternario la verdad que no conocía esa función gracias por el aporte